# Embedded Jetty no filter named cross-origin

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, servlet-filters, embedded-jetty

I am trying to implement cors in a embedded jetty server. I feel lost right now with this exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No filter named cross-origin
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.updateMappings(ServletHandler.java:1260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doStart(ServletHandler.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:955)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:896)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.projectsanatan.restsanatan.RestSanatan.start(RestSanatan.java:38)
    at org.projectsanatan.restsanatan.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

My code is

```java
    private void initServlets() {
        ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

        servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");
        
        ResourceConfig resourceCfg = new ResourceConfig();
        resourceCfg.packages(BookResource.class.getPackage().getName(), "/*");
        
        ServletContainer servletContainer = new ServletContainer(resourceCfg);
        
        ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(servletContainer);
        servletContextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/api/*");
//        servletContextHandler.addFilter(null, KEY, null)
        
        FilterHolder corsFilter = new FilterHolder();
        corsFilter.setInitParameter("allowedOrigins", "https://example.com");
        corsFilter.setInitParameter("allowedMethods", "POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,HEAD");
        corsFilter.setInitParameter("allowedHeaders", "X-PINGOTHER, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        corsFilter.setInitParameter("preflightMaxAge", "728000");
        corsFilter.setInitParameter("allowCredentials", "true");
        corsFilter.setInitParameter("chainPreflight", "false");
        
        CrossOriginFilter cors = new CrossOriginFilter();
        
        corsFilter.setFilter(cors);
        
        FilterMapping corsFilterMap = new FilterMapping();
        corsFilterMap.setFilterName("cross-origin");
        corsFilterMap.setPathSpec("/*");
        corsFilterMap.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.REQUEST));
        
        servletContextHandler.getServletHandler().addFilter(corsFilter, corsFilterMap);
        
        this.handlerList.addHandler(servletContextHandler);
        
        this.setHandler(this.handlerList);
    }
```

I am not very much experienced with jetty and servlet stuff so I am confused, help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Maybe try to set the filter name with FilterHolder#setName()

Comment: Not throwing any error now with that but the cors is not working either.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues.

1. Mapping of both Servlets and Filters is done by the `ServletContextHandler`, not the `ServletHandler`.
2. If you use a `FilterHolder` + Mapping with name, then you have to name your `FilterHolder`.
   Mapping with name is overly complicated for embedded-jetty use, it really only exists for `WEB-INF/web.xml` based configuration.  Just use the `FilterHolder` directly.
3. You are missing the required `ServletContextHandler` BaseResource declaration
4. You are missing the required `DefaultServlet` on your `ServletContext`
5. You are missing the `DefaultHandler` on your top level handler tree (usually set as last entry)

A correct setup would be like this ...

```java
ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");
// Base Resource is required for your setup
servletContextHandler.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(urlToStaticContent));

ResourceConfig resourceCfg = new ResourceConfig();
resourceCfg.packages(BookResource.class.getPackage().getName(), "/*");

ServletContainer servletContainer = new ServletContainer(resourceCfg);

ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(servletContainer);
servletContextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/api/*");

FilterHolder corsHolder = servletContextHandler.addFilter(CrossOriginFilter.class,
    "/*",
    EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.REQUEST));

corsHolder.setInitParameter("allowedOrigins", "https://example.com");
corsHolder.setInitParameter("allowedMethods", "POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,HEAD");
corsHolder.setInitParameter("allowedHeaders", "X-PINGOTHER, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
corsHolder.setInitParameter("preflightMaxAge", "728000");
corsHolder.setInitParameter("allowCredentials", "true");
corsHolder.setInitParameter("chainPreflight", "false");

// Default Servlet is Required
ServletHolder defaultHolder = new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class);
servletContextHandler.addServlet(defaultHolder, "/"); // default url-pattern

HandlerList handlerList = new HandlerList();
handlerList.addHandler(servletContextHandler);
// Default Handler is for requests that don't match a context above
// Such as requests that don't have a path that start with "/"
// It is safe to leave active, even in production, and will help with troubleshooting issues
handlerList.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());

server.setHandler(handlerList);
```

The Filter mapping of your `CrossOriginFilter` has specified the `DispatcherType` set of `INCLUDE` and `REQUEST`, that's a really odd setup.

Doing CORS from an `INCLUDE` (or `FORWARD`) dispatch is super awkward, skip it.

But you didn't specify `ASYNC`, which is actually super common.

I would change the mapping this way ...

```java
FilterHolder corsHolder = servletContextHandler.addFilter(CrossOriginFilter.class,
    "/*",
    EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ASYNC));
```

Things to keep in mind for using `CrossOriginFilter`.

1. It will only produce HTTP Response headers based on your configuration.
2. It does not "prevent" or "fail" any request that doesn't match your configuration.
3. Requests without a `Origin` request header will not trigger the `CrossOriginFilter`.

Comment: The server still does not return the required header.

```curl "http://localhost:5080/api/book/rv/mantras/10/129" --head --header "Origin: localhost"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 14 Apr 2022 14:42:19 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 2949
```

Comment: That `Origin` is not part of your configuration which specifies `"allowedOrigins", "https://example.com"`

Comment: And when you are testing CORS, never use `localhost` as it has special rules that often get in the way of success.